# VM : setTimeout is not working in browser vm.runInNewContext

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8, node-vm2

I am executing a JS script using vm module in browser like this with details below.

```
vm.runInNewContext(codeToEval, sandboxObject);
```

setTimeout, setInterval and other interval built in methods do not work, even if I expose them in sandboxObject created using `vm.createContext({setTimeout})`

```
console.log('start');
setTimeout(()=> {
     console.log('hello timeout');
 }, 2000);

 console.log('end');
```

**output:**

```
start
end
```

It is to be noted that when I add .bind(this) , then timeout works and breaks at that line saying .bind is not a function.

```
console.log('start');
setTimeout(()=> {
     console.log('hello timeout');
 }, 2000).bind(this);

 console.log('end');
```

**output:**

```
start
hello timeout
// and an error in console saying setTimeout(...).bind is not a function
// and end is not printed
```

**Chrome 70**

**Platform Ubuntu 18.04**

**V8**

Comment: I ended up creating my own custom `setTimeout`, explained here : https://gist.github.com/ahmadalibaloch/6c7d70244c83b90aa77bb83fa28cd0df

Answer (score -1):

Put `setTimeout` and other context dependencies into into sandboxObject and execute code like this

```js
let executionContext = {
  setTimeout,
}
vm.createContext(executionContext);
vm.runInContext(code, executionContext)
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. They were already doing that.